# Centering subfigure titles

Tags: subfloats, subcaption

In the figure below I am using subcaption. The titles of the subfigures are centered to the middle of the subfigure. This is correct, but because the graphs are very much skewed to the left, one gets the impression that the titles are not properly centered. Is there a way to center the titles not to the center of the subfigure but to the left-most part of the graphs?

[image]

Comment: It's well-nigh impossible to diagnose the situation from looking the formatted output. Do please show us the underlying LaTeX code.

Comment: I estimate, that you can solve your problem in showed images by use of the caption set up: `\captionsetup{margin={1em,0cm}, singlelinecheck=false}` , for example.

Comment: Alternatively one can modify the images to make them centered.  For tikz, use `\pgfresetboundingbox` at the end, followed by `\path (...);` for whatever point you want centered.

Answer (score 1):

It could be done by redefining the `\captionsetup` for each subfigure, adding some `\hspace` to displace the `\subcaption` left or right.

Notice the different signs of the lengths.
[image: upit]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{subcaption}
\usepackage{graphicx}

\newlength{\hangright}
\setlength{\hangright}{50pt} %for subfigure (a) center to right

\newlength{\hangleft}
\setlength{\hangleft}{-40pt}%for subfigure (b) center to left

\DeclareCaptionFormat{hangright}{\hspace*{\hangright}#1#2#3\par}    
\DeclareCaptionFormat{hangleft}{\hspace*{\hangleft}#1#2#3\par}

\begin{document}
    
    \begin{figure}
        \captionsetup[sub]{format=hangright, font=it}           
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
            \subcaption{sub caption c}      
            \label{fig:figure-1.c}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-c}         
        \end{subfigure}
        \hfil
        \captionsetup[sub]{format=hangleft, font=it}
        \begin{subfigure}{.4\linewidth}
            \subcaption{sub caption b}
            \label{fig:figure-1.b}
            \includegraphics[width=\linewidth]{example-image-b}         
        \end{subfigure}
        \caption{My figures}
        \label{fig:figure1}
    \end{figure}
    
\end{document}
```